# Syncing programs across different machins

Tags: synchronization, rsync

I need sync my computer (where I'm developing my programs) and our computing cluster (where the programs are actually being run). Previously, I tried github. I regularly push my files to github and pull from the server. But the problem is our computing cluster does not have access to internet. I was using sshfs to mount my home directory on the cluster to a local directory and run github there. The sshfs introduces problems once in a while. None of the suggested solution worked always.

Then I tried rsync & make. But every time it copies everything and does not check for the changes which takes a long time to copy and since files are updated it takes a long time to compile as well (a few minutes).

Is there any other way to do it? My local machine is a MacBook and our computing cluster runs CentOS I guess and I don't have access to install anything on the server.

Comment: "our computing cluster does not have access to internet" --> go to the server room and copy the files from a flash drive.

Comment: You could always just use an internal git server instead of github. There's no reason to use sshfs here, use regular ssh, or the native git protocol, or http, or nfs etc.

Comment: @JakubZaverka There is local network!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out that rsync does the job perfectly. I just needed -c option. The option asks rsync to just copy the changed files over. I works fine yet there are some minor issues with the *make* due to the timing difference between the two machines.